# I would like to integrate Keycloak with Spring Boot 2 and Swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, keycloak

Now, I use Spring boot version 2.0.0.RELEASE and Swagger version 3.1.6 and Keycloak of Jboss. I would like to know how to configure in application.yml then let swagger can get access_token from Keycloak.

Thanks for your help

Comment: This does not make any sense. Why would swagger need an access token?

Answer (score 5):

An initial decision to make is whether to say that the user accessing the swagger page needs to have an access token (i.e. the url pattern for swagger is secured and the user has to log in to get to swagger) or you exclude the swagger URLs from keycloak so that its UI can be accessed without needing a token.

If you're using the [keycloak spring boot adapter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak) then the URL patterns to secure (and which roles are required to access them) are configured in the application.yml or application.properties file as security-constraints. As properties an example is:

```
keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=user
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/customers/*
```

This could be translated to yaml as:

```
keycloak:
  security-constraints[0]:
    -authRoles[0]: user
    -securityCollections[0]:
      -patterns[0]: /customers/*
```

(Real yml example at https://github.com/codemonkeybr/skip/blob/master/skip-cart/src/main/resources/application.yml#L29 )

Anything not covered by security-constraints is not restricted. There's a similar way of doing this with spring security if you're not using the official keycloak adpater - normally then you do it in a SecurityConfiguration java class.

Then you face decisions based on your [chosen oauth2 flow](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/oauth2/) and whether you use the 'try it out' feature. You can display descriptions without necessarily needing a token but 'try it out' does need a token. That yaml example above also has a way of telling swagger the token issuer url:

```
swagger:
  auth:
    token-url: ${keycloak.auth-server-url}/realms/${keycloak.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token/
    client-id: skip-local
```

That config is read by a [java swagger configuration class](https://github.com/codemonkeybr/skip/blob/3a5f7e385f77e488610f7471d8f887b35db3edcb/skip-cart/src/main/java/org/tesso/skip/cart/SwaggerConfig.java) and is part of a [whole example](https://github.com/codemonkeybr/skip) that you could run. This specific question of how to configure swagger to work with an oauth2 token is not specific to keycloak and is general [swagger-oauth2 configuration for which there is a guide at baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api) and there's an example using a different mode in [Keycloak integration in Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918845/keycloak-integration-in-swagger)

Comment: Thanks so much for your anwser. I will adapt like your instruction