# Angular Frontend with Spring Boot Security and Keycloak

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

i struggle a little with various tutorials pointing in every direction whitout working at all for me.

The idea is quite simple: 
Having a Angular Frontend with a secured Spring Boot Backend put together using Keycloak as a identity provider.

**Frontend:**

For the frontend I found that one: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular which works for the frontend quite well. I go to the page, get a redirection to the keycloak login page and get pack with a JWT Token in my pockets.

In Keycloak I configured a client with protocol 'openid-connect' and access type 'public'

**Backend:**

For the Backend I try to use Spring Boot as a Resource Server 
added those depenencies to my build gradle:

```
implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose")
implementation("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.4.RELEASE")
implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server")
```

had a security config like that:

```
private val AUTH_WHITELIST: Array<String> = arrayOf(
        // -- swagger ui
        "/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources",
        "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/ui",
        "/configuration/security",
        "/swagger-ui.html",
        "/webjars/**"
)


@Throws(Exception::class)
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    http.cors()
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(*AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()
            .and().csrf().disable()
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwkSetUri(this.authProperties.jwt.jwkSetUri);
    // .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
}
```

and added the following properties to application.yml

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/{{realm}}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/{{realm}}
```

In Keycloak i also created a Client with  protocol 'openid-connect' and access type 'bearer-only'

For try out the backend i use swagger and create therefore another client in keycloak protocol 'openid-connect' and access type 'public'
and followed this instructions: [Keycloak integration in Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918845/keycloak-integration-in-swagger) which also works very well.

**Frontend + Backend:**

Now i try to bring the stuff together.
I create a service in the frontend calling the REST API. 
I see the CORS working (OPTION Call first returning 200)
Then the GET returns 401 even with set Authorization Header:

```
Authorization       bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR…hz0zWAU3hFQR87stc8alj9asJqZPw
```

After setup the security logging to debug it says something like

> 2019-01-03 14:30:58.183 DEBUG 17884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]
>   o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated
>   SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token:
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@355bb1b2:
>   Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated:
>   true; Details:
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e:
>   RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities:
>   ROLE_ANONYMOUS'

Now i have no idea, what to do. Maybe anyone could help.
Thx

Comment: made some progress by using the keycloak-spring-security-adapter and the keycloak-spring-boot-starter Version 4.8.1 and some inspiration from here: https://blog.codecentric.de/2017/09/keycloak-und-spring-security-teil-2-integration-von-keycloak-in-spring-security/ .. now getting a 403 :-)

Comment: Exactly my scenario did you manage to get it working?

Comment: Yeah.. You have also much less pain if you use micronaut 